# How to include .css code in a WordPress page template?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to set up a template that will apply some .css code to hide the header, footer and breadcrumbs on my landing pages.

I've created a css folder in my child theme, created a .css file with the code below and works perfectly with the function under the code:

```
 #header-wrap, #navi-wrap.site-header, #footer-wrap, #footer.clearfix, #sidebar.secondary.clearfix, #breadcrumbs, .page-title {
    display:none
}
```

Function in my child theme:

```
function wpse_enqueue_page_template_styles() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'template-fullwidth.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'page-template', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/landing-page.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_page_template_styles' );
```

I have another .css code though, that changes the link colour from the website default Blue to White, in my Adidtional CSS for my theme and it works, but I would like to include it in my .css file, so I don't have to apply it to every page separately:

```
.page-id-2934 a.wp-block-button__link.has-white-color.has-text-color.has-background.no-border-radius{
    color:white;
}
```

Problem is, when I add this code as it is (without the page id, obviously) in my existing .css file, an exclamation mark shows up on the left and when I hover it tells me to not use adjoining clases, that `a,wp...` it's Overqualified and I should use only `.wp-block-button__link` without element name and I don't know what that means.
When I leave only `.wp-block-button__link {color:white;}` it's not working.

I also have some pages with different buttons and the code that works in the Additional CSS is

```
.page-id-3547 a.uagb-buttons-repeater {
    color:white;
}
```

...But when I put that in the .css file I get the same message: with `a...` is overqualified and when I leave just `.uagb-buttons-repeater {color:white;}` it doesn't work.

So, long story short, I would like to add the white link .css code in the .css file, so that my landing pages button links are white, not blue and I was hoping to add both codes, so that it works with both button types.
Alternatively, I could just use the second button type (`a.uag...`) and change it on the existing pages.

Thanks

Comment: If “shorter” selectors don’t work, then you likely have other rules with higher specificity, that overwrite the properties you are trying to set. Use your browser dev tools to find out where the style that applies to the elements comes from.

Comment: @CBroe I'm afraid I don't know how to do that

Comment: Where is the "additional css" that works? In the theme customizer?

Comment: If the "overqualified" message is only a warning, you could ignore it in the first place, to move on to a solution and thus to understanding the problem. If I understand you correctly, you added additional styles for every page id? There should be a more generic replacement for ".page-id-2934". All of that said, you probably want to ask your question with a better chance for an answer at the topical stack exchange site https://wordpress.stackexchange.com